# Parsing a bmml file

Tags: c#

Ive been working on this for a few days and I cant figure it out. I'm new to XML and parsing but I was able to retrieve bmml data from a website and i want to be able to extract an image file name from the bmml file. I tried using XPath but it dosen't seem to work.

```
bmml:bmml xmlns="http://www.X.com/2002/bmml" xmlns:bmml="http://www.X.com/2002/bmml" xmlns:cg="http://www.X.com/2002/cg" xmlns:ctrl="http://www.X.com/2002/control" xmlns:geo="http://www.X.com/2002/geometry" xmlns:res="http://www.X.com/2002/resource" xmlns:lyr="http://www.X.com/2002/lyric" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <bmml:context name="ctx1">
- <bmml:devices>
  <bmml:device xsi:type="cg:character-generator" name="dev1" /> 
  </bmml:devices>
- <bmml:resources resourceCount="100" totalCount="492">
- <bmml:resource name="image0" moniker="ABC Australia Logo" context="NEWSRED" uuid="FD076559-97F1-4B7A-BD99-864E0A99A7D6" xsi:type="res:image" format="tga" width="0" height="0">
  <bmml:title>ABC Australia Logo.tga</bmml:title> 
  <bmml:description /> 
  <bmml:keywords /> 
  <bmml:asset-class>4</bmml:asset-class> 
  <bmml:author>/X</bmml:author> 
  <bmml:version /> 
  <bmml:subject /> 
  <bmml:filename>..\ABC Australia Logo.tga</bmml:filename> 
  <bmml:filesize>8294418</bmml:filesize> 
  <bmml:url>NEWSRED/images/FD076559-97F1-4B7A-BD99-864E0A99A7D6.tga</bmml:url> 
  <bmml:alpha>true</bmml:alpha> 
  <bmml:created>1274893542000</bmml:created> 
  <bmml:modified>1274893542000</bmml:modified> 
  <bmml:accessed>1277933686000</bmml:accessed> 
- <bmml:proxy name="proxy0" class="thumbnail" xsi:type="res:image" height="0" width="0">
  **<bmml:url>NEWSRED/images/FD076559-97F1-4B7A-BD99-864E0A99A7D6/thumbnail.jpg</bmml:url>** 
  </bmml:proxy>
- <bmml:proxy name="proxy1" class="asset" xsi:type="res:image" height="0" width="0">
  <bmml:url>NEWSRED/images/FD076559-97F1-4B7A-BD99-864E0A99A7D6/asset.jpg</bmml:url> 
  </bmml:proxy>
  </bmml:resource>
```

Comment: Three things you forgot to post so that we can have a base for discussion: an example of `bmml` file, the exact part of this file that you are trying to extract and what you've tried so far (the exact code I mean, not just saying that you've tried `XPath`). Now that I am thinking you could add a fourth thing: an eventual error message or the wrong result you are getting from your code instead of saying `it doesn't seem to work`.

Comment: Well i tried to follow a bunch of XPath tutorials online and and none of them were able to work with parsing the bmml properly.

Comment: @Katianie, your comment doesn't really bring us any closer to be able to help you. See my first comment to understand why.

Comment: Im trying to get the data between <bmml:url> and </bmml:url>

Comment: What you've posted is not a valid XML file. It contains `-` and unclosed tags.

Comment: well if I post the whole file it will be huge...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses the [XPathSelectElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) extension method and retrieves all the `bmml:url` values in the document:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("bmml", "http://www.X.com/2002/bmml");
        var urls = doc.XPathSelectElements("//bmml:url", nsmgr);
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(url.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice the usage of a [namespace manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) that allows to correctly perform the `XPath` queries.

---

UPDATE:

It seems that the usage of the [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) extension method was not as obvious as I thought initially. Things to make sure:

1. Your project is targeting .NET 3.5 or higher
2. You've referenced the `System.Xml.Linq.dll` assembly in your project
3. You've added the `using System.Xml.XPath` in order to bring the [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) into scope

Comment: when u say XDocument you meen XmlDocument or XPathDocument. also I cant find XPathSelectElements.

Comment: No, XDocument means, well..., `XDocument` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx). It doesn't mean `XmlDocument` nor `XPathDocument`. It has nothing to do with those classes by the way. As for the `XPathSelectElements` method, it is an extension method defined in the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace in the `System.Xml.Linq assembly`. Read the documentation (the link I provided) and use proper usings and reference proper assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that xml data is well formed or not (one would hope).  However, if all else failes open with a string reader and replace the bmml:bmml with xml.  Not sure if this would work and I may be way off base...I do believe Darin has a great solution though requirements for using linq and .net 3.5 may not work for you.

:)~  Good Luck.